# Keep all the data.table when aggregating a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I would like to aggregate a data.table by a list of column and keep all the columns at the end.

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,4,6,4)
B <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
C <- c(10,11,23,8,8,1,3)
D <- c(2,3,5,9,7,8,4)
dt <- data.table(A,B,C,D)
```

Now I want to aggregate the column B paste(B,sep=";") by A and C and keep the column D too at the end. Do you know a way to do it please?

**EDIT**

this is what i obtained using `dt[, newCol := toString(B), .(A, C)]`

`A B  C D newCol
1: 1 a 10 2      a
2: 2 b 11 3      b
3: 3 c 23 5      c
4: 4 d  8 9   d, e
5: 4 e  8 7   d, e
6: 6 f  1 8      f
7: 4 g  3 4      g`

But i would like to obtain

`A B  C D newCol
1: 1 a 10 2      a
2: 2 b 11 3      b
3: 3 c 23 5      c
4: 4 d  8 9   d, e
6: 6 f  1 8      f
7: 4 g  3 4      g`

Comment: Have u tried `:=` to create a column i.e. `dt[, newCol := toString(B), .(A, C)]`

Comment: it doesn't work when i try

Comment: I worked for me using your dataset

Comment: let me try again

Comment: Looks like you need `unique` with `by` i.e. `unique(dt, by = c('A', 'C', 'newCol'))`

Comment: How do you use it ?

Comment: my comment is updated with the code

Comment: Nice thank you, and is there a way to replace the toString by a paste or something else so i can choose the separator ?

Comment: Yes. `toString` is just a special case of `paste`. See `?paste` for options.